# convert string with backslashes followed by numbers to path

Tags: python, string, path, escaping

I am getting a string representing a path from a database. unfortunatly that path doesn't have double backslashes and only single ones. sometimes these are followed by numbers which python than converts, messing up the path. how can i get a correct path out of example: \depotcentral\foo\2017 which currently gets converted to \depotcentraloo�7

i tried `re.escape` and `.encode('string-escape')`

```
path = '\\depotcentral\foo\2017'

path = path.encode('string-escape')
print(path)
```

What I want at the end is a `os.path` without the string literal conversion

Answer (score 0):

Replace backslash with double backslash in your string. You will escape the backslash.

```py
path = '\depotcentral\foo\2017'
path = path.replace("\", "\\")
print(path)
```

Comment: this doesn't actually work and throws an error. even if i try .replace('\\', '\\\\') i still don't get the correct result and get: \\depotcentraloo7